# Issue with serving uploaded files from filesystem

Tags: django

I made a project using Django 1.5.4 and have now a problem with serving files being uploaded locally. My urls.py look like this now:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root='')
```

In models.py there is an ImageField of a class Product:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and a method for displaying it:

```
def display_photo(self):
    return '<img src="%s" />' % (self.photo)

display_photo.short_description = 'Photo of a product'
display_photo.allow_tags = True
```

And, finally, MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nervosa/DjangoProjects/Sit_test/uploads/'
```

Still firebug shows an error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/nervosa/DjangoProjects/Sit_test/uploads/cover.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: What's in the `MEDIA_URL` setting?

Comment: Here it is - MEDIA_URL = ''

Comment: You need to set `MEDIA_URL` to whatever will point to your `MEDIA_ROOT` when accessed via your webserver.

Comment: Okay, i've set them like this:
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nervosa/DjangoProjects/Sit_test/uploads/'
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
Got the same error.

Comment: Sorry, lot's of stuff in your question is unclear for me. Is cover.jpg in media folder or not? Could you print your settings file, whole. And also your *whole* view. I don't understand why do you use display_photo() method, not template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just needed to modify urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^uploads/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

The whole class Product contained by models.py now looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    height = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    weight = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_photo/')
    thumbnail = ThumbnailerImageField(default='', upload_to='products_photo_thumbnails')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def display_photo(self):
        return '<img src="%s" />' % (self.photo.url)

    display_photo.short_description = 'Photo of a product'
    display_photo.allow_tags = True
```

Sorry for not providing my ModelAdmin - here it is:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Title of a product',         {'fields':['title']}),
        ('Parameters of a product',    {'fields':['height', 'weight', 'color']}),
        ('Upload a photo',                      {'fields':['photo']}),
        ('Photo',             {'fields':['display_photo']}),
    ]
    list_display = ['title', 'height', 'weight', 'color']
    readonly_fields = ('display_photo',)

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

And finally - MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL - in my case they should be:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nervosa/DjangoProjects/Sit_test/'
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

Now image is displayed properly after uploading. Thanks for attention and answers.